# How to enable replace-by-fee via command-line in bitcoin-core?

Tags: bitcoin-core, replace-by-fee, command-line-options

Alright, so I'm convinced replace-by-fee is a good thing. I've read it's opt-in, so how can I enable it in my bitcoin-core wallet? I don't find any flag to pass it when launching it. I want all my outgoing transaction have replace-by-fee enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitcoin Core v0.14.0 introduced the startup option `walletrbf=1` which causes any transactions sent from the wallet to opt into replaceability. Since Bitcoin Core v0.16.0 transactions created from the GUI would signal replaceability by default.
Bitcoin Core v24.0.1 changed the default value to `walletrbf=1` which extended this behavior also to all transactions created via RPC.

Answer (score 4):

According to bitcoin core version [0.12.0 release notes](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/fc23fee690477828e84a7886dbf208e9a96e82e2/doc/release-notes/release-notes-0.12.0.md#opt-in-replace-by-fee-transactions):

> It is now possible to replace transactions in the transaction memory pool of Bitcoin Core 0.12 nodes.
>
> Transaction replacement can be disabled with a new command line option, -mempoolreplacement=0.
>
> Note that the wallet in Bitcoin Core 0.12 does not yet have support for creating transactions that would be replaceable under BIP 125.

So the mempool can be configured to accept/reject replacement transactions, but there is not support yet for creating replaceable transactions.

Bitcoin [v0.12.1 release notes](https://bitcoin.org/en/release/v0.12.1) do not include any modification regarding RBF.

The functionality for the wallets is split in two:

- Mark the transactions as RBF ([pull request not merged yet](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/7132)).
- Replace fee of transactions that were already sent using RBF (no code or pull request in Core yet, but [some scripts by Peter Todd can be used](https://github.com/petertodd/replace-by-fee-tools)).

Comment: so it's not implemented yet? what do you mean?

Comment: Yes, it's not implemented yet.

Comment: convenience functions to create replacement transactions are not implemented yet.

Comment: @renlord, ok but how to mark my outgoing transactions as replace-by-fee enabled?

Comment: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/44510/what-wallets-currently-support-rbf/44524#44524